# Why add a placeholder alongside bash variable checks?

Tags: bash, shell, syntax, arguments

I've seen many shell scripts that examine the input args using a comparison to a placeholder string, e.g.

```
if
[ "x$1" == "x" ]; then
xyz()
fi
```

I'm assuming this to be a best practice, because of how ubiquitous it seems to be.

Personally, I've always done an input arg examination without placeholders:

```
if
[ "$1" == "" ]; then
xyz()
fi
```

What is the reason for using the placeholder? What potential pitfalls are avoided using that syntax?

Comment: The reason is an old bug of bash. BTW, `==` is a bashism, a single `=` is the standard

Comment: Did `bash` itself ever have that problem? I though it was just a carryover from old versions of the original Bourne shell.

Comment: Some old shell (or more specifically, some old implementation of `test`/`[`) simply couldn't handle empty strings, even when properly quoted. The `x` ensured that neither operand was ever empty, even if `$1` expands to the empty string.

Comment: There are a *lot* of poorly written shell scripts out there. Questionable practices employed by people who knew the risks they were taking (either out of necessity or due to laziness) were picked up by people who didn't understand the reasons, and they kept using the same techniques even when no longer necessary or in places where it was flat-out wrong to do so.

Comment: There's a partial explanation on the Bash wiki under [pitfall 4](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#A.5B_.24foo_.3D_.22bar.22_.5D). `The x"$foo" hack is required for code that must run on very ancient shells which lack [[ and have a more primitive [, which gets confused if $foo begins with a - or is ! or (. On said older systems, [ only requires extra caution for the token on the left-hand side of =; it handles the right-hand token correctly.`

Comment: @tjm3772 Even though everyone said something similar, you gave the GreyCat source, so I'll give you the credit ;) can you submit as an answer?

Comment: See [Cargo cult programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cargo_cult_programming).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a partial explanation on the Bash wiki under [pitfall 4](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#A.5B_.24foo_.3D_.22bar.22_.5D).

> The x"$foo" hack is required for code that must run on very ancient shells which lack [[ and have a more primitive [, which gets confused if $foo begins with a - or is ! or (. On said older systems, [ only requires extra caution for the token on the left-hand side of =; it handles the right-hand token correctly.

You should ideally never need to do this for a shell script you write today, but it's good to understand why older shell scripts do it sometimes.

Comment: Given that this is a FAQ, probably find a duplicate and vote to close instead of post a new answer. The duplicate mechanism is important because it helps collect all relevant answers in one place, even if the question can be articulated in many different ways.